# Trying to use intrinsic sizing value fill-content, but chrome is not accepting it

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am trying to get a div to fit to only the content using intrinsic sizing, but chrome dev tools seems to be rejecting that style.

In the dev tools, that style has a strike-though through it and a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark as if it is an invalid style.'

The style gets a strike-through if I do it without vendor prefixes or with so none of the following are working:

```
.box{
    width:-moz-fit-content;
    width:-webkit-fit-content;
    width:fit-content;
}
```

All of them have a strike-through through them.

What am I doing wrong? I have the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome and they are supposed to support this.

Update:

Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing in chrome dev tools:
http://cl.ly/image/1k0I21192Q36

Comment: This should work fine. Are you sure nothing else is overriding it later - something more specific, further down the css, or even altered via any js you are using? Maybe you could post a link to a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: @ChrisBoon It is not being over-ridden by anything. It is just being strike-throughed as if something is over-writing it or if it is invalid styling. Here is a screenshot of what I see in dev tools: http://cl.ly/image/1k0I21192Q36

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome 22–29: http://jsfiddle.net/fy8jz/

Comment: @DavidStorey Looks like it is being parsed fine, but dev tools just doesn't recognise it. As in dev tools, I am still getting those styles  ( fit-content on height ) as crossed out. Here is your js fiddle: http://cl.ly/image/3p2W0m2E0i2r

Comment: @irfanmir that is now what I am seeing. They are not crossed out in Web Inspector on my machine.

Comment: @DavidStorey That is weird. Anyway, I learned that why they were probably crossed out was because the fit-content can only be a value for width not for height.

Comment: @irfanmir that isn’t true, as it is accepted in my Chrome, and the spec explicitly states: ‘width’, ‘min-width’, ‘max-width’, ‘height’, ‘min-height’, ‘max-height’

Comment: @DavidStorey so the answer I chose below is wrong?

Comment: @DavidStorey I'm not sure I follow you. Min-height and max-height are fine to use for height, but he was using fit-content - the definition of which is (MDN): 'The larger of [the intrinsic minimum width] or [the smaller of the intrinsic preferred width and the available width]. This explicitly says the size is for widths. Even if it is somehow not being crossed out on your browser can you explain what actual effect is? A webkit bug ticket does imply that they once tried to get it working for height but abandoned it as Mozilla was only doing width: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38919

Comment: MDN might say it is only for widths, but the actual spec says it is for height as well (and min-height and max-height too). http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing/#width-height-keywords And Chrome excepts height just fine. I've not tested min-height and max-height.

Comment: @DavidStorey Okay, then I will use it for height. Thank you for your clarifications.

Comment: @DavidStorey My bad, I didn't check official spec as I had it in my head that this was a proprietary thing that wasn't in there. Was using Chrome 27 at home and height was crossed out, but checking beta(28) and canary(29) at work I see they do accept it, although Webkit Nightly still does not. However even in Chrome Canary the rule itself doesn't in any way change the behavior of the div so I still don't think it should be used - unless you have a working case for why to use it on height? Maybe it does something when paired with multiple columns or css regions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have written in your answer:

```
.box{
    width:-moz-fit-content;
    width:-webkit-fit-content;
    width:fit-content;
}
```

should work totally fine. However the code in your screenshot:

```
div.container{
    height:-webkit-fit-content;
    height:fit-content;
}
```

won't work. This is because fit-content only applies to width and not height.
See the Mozilla Developer Network for working values for width and height - there are way more available for width:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width

According to MDN, the fit-content width does the following:

> fit-content Experimental The larger of: the intrinsic minimum width
>   the smaller of the intrinsic preferred width and the available width

So for a height you can expect a div to expand it's height to fit the content within it (unless the content is positioned absolutely or floated). To get it to fulfil the last part (making sure it doesn't exceed the available space) you could add `max-height:100%;` depending on the structure of your html.

Comment: Ah, okay. So it doesn't work as a value for height. Thank you for explaining that!